# Handle Firefox native dialog windows with Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, browser-automation, selenium-ide

I'm new using Selenium IDE (and as a QA).

I'm testing my Web application on Firefox and I have an export button that downloads an Excel file. My problem is how to handle the window dialog native of the browser (in this case, the download window), because when the download step is executed I get this error: `Timed out after 30000ms`

I searched on the Internet about this topic, but I can't found a solution to my problem.

Is it possible to handle the native windows of Firefox use Selenium IDE, without using Selenium Driver?

I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can change the settings of Firefox so that it just download without showing a download file dialog. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-firefox-behavior-when-open-file

You cannot handle native OS dialogs with Selenium IDE, if you can't disable the download dialog, then your only option is dropping the IDE and writing Selenium tests in code and combine it with something like Auto-IT: http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/autoit-selenium-webdriver/

Comment: It didn't work for me

Comment: Hmm, than I have to disappoint you, because if I answer your question can you handle native windows from Selenium IDE the answer is: NO. :(